# How to write complex recursive maria db query

Tags: recursion, mariadb, common-table-expression

Im trying to write a recursive query for a use on a old and poorly designed database - and so the queries get quite complex.

Here is the (relevant) table relationships
[image]

Because people asked - here is the creation code for these tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CircuitLayout(
    CircuitLayoutID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (CircuitLayoutID)
);

CREATE TABLE LitCircuit (
    LitCircuitID int,
    CircuitLayoutID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (LitCircuitID)
    FOREIGN KEY (CircuitLayoutID) REFERENCES CircuitLayout(CircuitLayoutID)
);

CREATE TABLE CircuitLayoutItem(
    CircuitLayoutItemID int,
    CircuitLayoutID int,
    TableName varchar(255),
    TablePK int,
    PRIMARY KEY (CircuitLayoutItemID)
    FOREIGN KEY (CircuitLayoutID) REFERENCES CircuitLayout(CircuitLayoutID)
);
```

TableName refers to another table in the database and thus TablePK is a primary key from the specified table

One of the valid options for TableName is LitCircuit

I'm trying to write a query that will select a circuit and any circuit it is related to

I am having trouble understanding the syntax for recursive ctes

my non-functional attempt is this:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE carries AS (
    SELECT LitCircuit.LitCircuitID AS recurseList FROM LitCircuit
    JOIN CircuitLayoutItem ON LitCircuit.CircuitLayoutID = CircuitLayoutItem.CircuitLayoutID
    WHERE CircuitLayoutItem.TableName = "LitCircuit" AND CircuitLayoutItem.TablePK IN (00340)
    UNION
    SELECT LitCircuit.LitCircuitID AS CircuitIDs FROM LitCircuit
    JOIN CircuitLayout ON LitCircuit.CircuitLayoutID = CircuitLayoutItem.CircuitLayoutID
    WHERE CircuitLayoutItem.TableName = "LitCircuit" AND CircuitLayoutItem.TablePK IN (SELECT recurseList FROM carries)
) 
SELECT * FROM carries;
```

the "00340" is a dummy number for testing, and it would get replaced with an actual list in usage

What i'm attempting to do is get a list of LitCircuitIDs based on one or many LitCircuitIDs - that's the anchor member, and that works fine.
What I want to do is take this result and feed it back into itself.

I lack an understanding of how to access data from the anchor member:
I don't know if it is a table with the columns from the select in the anchor or if it is simply a list of resulting values
I dont understand if or where I need to include "carries" in the FROM part of a query

If I were to write this function in python I would do it like this:

```py
def get_circuits(circuit_list):
    result_list = []
    for layout_item_key, layout_item in CircuitLayoutItem.items():
            if layout_item['TableName'] == "LitCircuit" and layout_item['TablePK'] in circuit_list:
                layout = layout_item['CircuitLayoutID']
                for circuit_key, circuit in LitCircuit.items():
                    if circuit["CircuitLayoutID"] == layout:
                        result_list.append(circuit_key)
    result_list.extend(get_circuits(result_list))
    return result_list
```

How do I express this in SQL?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I'm not good enough at ASCII art to draw an ERD in text - I shall modify the question to include table creation code.

Comment: @GeorgRichter also note this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292055/17981284 - If you have a suggestion on how to post an ERD the "correct" way, I'm all ears.

Comment: You can use a link to the picture or you could use for simple diagrams a tool, e.g. https://asciiflow.com

Comment: First it might be convenient if your anchor and body include all columns you need. As is `recurseList` is `LitCircuit.LitCircuitID` in your anchor, its compared against the wrong item in your recrusive body.`CircuitLayoutItem.TablePK` appears to have no relation to `recurseList`. Perhaps you meant `CircuitLayoutItem.CircuitLayoutID IN (SELECT recurseList FROM carries`

Comment: @danblack I was attempting to use the result set from the anchor as the input for the `CircuitLayoutItem.TablePK IN` part. So the only column I need is LitCircuitIDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

danblack's comment made me realize something I was missing:

Here is what I was trying to do:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE carries AS (
    SELECT LitCircuit.LitCircuitID FROM LitCircuit
    JOIN CircuitLayoutItem ON LitCircuit.CircuitLayoutID = CircuitLayoutItem.CircuitLayoutID
    WHERE CircuitLayoutItem.TableName = 'LitCircuit' AND CircuitLayoutItem.TablePK IN (00340)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LitCircuit.LitCircuitID FROM carries
    JOIN CircuitLayoutItem ON carries.LitCircuitID = CircuitLayoutItem.TablePK
    JOIN LitCircuit ON CircuitLayoutItem.CircuitLayoutID = LitCircuit.CircuitLayoutID
    WHERE CircuitLayoutItem.TableName = 'LitCircuit'
)
SELECT DISTINCT LitCircuitID FROM carries;
```

I did not think of the CTE as a table to query against - rather just a result set, so I did not realize you have to SELECT from it - or in general treat it like a table.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Thanks for your own words. Additionally `carries` as a result set "table" carries the anchor, or in later iterations, the result of the previous recursive query. When there is no result in the recursive query it end. And then in the final query, `carries` has the full set or anchor and every other recursive iteration. Happy Recursive CTEing.